# Where can I find a database for dielectric constants in the visible range?

Tags: electrostatics, resource-recommendations, dielectric

I am looking for a database of dielectric constants in the visible range and I could not find them by Googling, so I was wondering whether anybody here knows where I can find those parameters for some common materials (water, several oils, gold and so on) and several wavelengths in the visible range?

Comment: http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/relative-permittivity-d_1660.html This has several oils, and comes on the first page of Google search.

Comment: For glass, see Kitamura, http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~pilon/Publications/AO2007-1.pdf‎ . Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65812/

Answer (score 2):

A good database with several materials could be found here  [RefractiveIndex.INFO](http://refractiveindex.info)  .

It could be accesed online for download in different formats.