# Why doesn't refraction occur when looking through a magnifying glass?

Tags: visible-light

Why isn't light broken up into various colors when we look at something through a magnifying glass?

Comment: Light does get dispersed in a lens (magnifying glass uses a lens); the phenomenon is known as chromatic aberration.

Comment: Duplicate? http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/228400/dispersion-of-light-through-a-prism-but-not-through-glass-or-lense

Comment: Tutorial here https://www.microscopyu.com/tutorials/chromatic and image here Nice image here. http://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-chromatic-aberration-illustrated-using-a-magnifying-glass-133821.html