# Does Lens disperse light along with refracting? Why doesn't it depict in diagrams?

Tags: optics, refraction, dispersion

Why we depicts every diagram studying in ray optics lenses as 'a ray that is passed after retracting from lenses'?

I mean to say , lens is made of glass with non parallel faces so it should disperse light after light is passes through into 7 colors not simply retracting? I thought it same for water but I got to know angle if dispersion is extremely small that light appears mostly undispersed but what happened here? Here lens made of glass with high enough refractive index needed to split ray?

**Why we show Only prism dispersing such a great wide spectrum not any 'other medium' in which light refracts ?**

Comment: Of course. This is called [chromatic aberration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_aberration)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do convex lenses not disperse light like prisms, given that entry and exit points aren't parallel?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/341038/why-do-convex-lenses-not-disperse-light-like-prisms-given-that-entry-and-exit-p) Also see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/228400/123208

Comment: @PM 2Ring, yes they help me in conceptually clearing although these topics are of much higher level than I am in! Still I am giving my best to learn. I have one query on the second link you send "physics.stackexchange.com/q/228400/123208" , in that second answer have mentioned a point that I needed to ask ,  " In that he said dispersion DO occur in every media but!! It depends on refractive index of that medium as more refractive index than the more the space between different frequencies so more we can notice it OR the angle between opposite faces matter a lot , as they can exaturate ...

Comment: The effect caused by refraction on ray that is dispersion medium" **So...I am confused whether refractive index affect dispersion ( a wide and clear spectrum or a hardly visible spectrum) OR the angle between face affect dispersion rate OR both at same time??**

Comment: [Dispersion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispersion_(optics)) occurs because the refractive index is not constant: it varies with the frequency.

Answer (score 2):

The sort of diagrams to which you refer are highly simplified models of how light interacts with lenses. The lenses do, of course, disperse light- the effect is known as chromatic aberration, and the design of optical system (eg binoculars) requires it to be taken into account and minimised through various techniques. The reason why dispersion isn't shown typically in ray diagrams it that to do so would make them far too complicated for the sorts of scenarios they are designed to illustrate.

Comment: But why the dispersion is not like a wide spectrum in prism type?? Why it is hardly visible

Comment: Because of the shape and the materials of the lens. A prism is designed to disperse light- a lens is designed not to. Different types of glass disperse light by different amounts. Look up chromatic aberration on wikipedia and you will find lots of information about it.