# How does refractive index increase in anomalous dispersion?

Tags: optics, refraction, dispersion

Refractive index generally increases with decrease in wavelength but in anomalous dispersion it decreases with decrease in wavelength. What causes it to be like that?

Comment: This is sort of a duplicate (subset) of https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/65812/why-do-prisms-work-why-is-refraction-frequency-dependent , and I think the answer to your question is covered in my own answer to that question.

Comment: @Ben Crowell sorry, I still didn't understand why the refractive index behaves opposite to the normal when it comes to anomalous dispersion.