# Why violet light bends the most?

Tags: visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, refraction, wavelength, dispersion

I have read about refraction through a triangular prism,rainbow formation and other natural phenomena.They all told about the strong bending of violet light .
I know that it has a shorter wavelength and high frequency.From the sources I searched I get to a conclusion that it is because of the above mentioned property.I also know that it has a smaller critical angle.what accounts for such properties?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65812/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0):

when light travels through a medium, it interacts with atoms or molecules in the medium. It brings temporary deformation of electron clouds near atoms or molecules and the energy retained is re-emitted without energy loss unless being absorbed by atoms or molecules in the medium. This interaction takes a little time and that's why light has different speed in different medium.
Then why a violet light bends more stronger than other? this is because refractive index varies with wavelength(or frequency). As we know, light has same speed 'c' in the vacuum(refractive index=1), but has different speed in different medium depending on the wavelength. I recommend you to look up 'dispersion curve'.

Comment: This kind of rephrases the OP's question, without actually answering it. Why does the *refractive index varies with wavelength*?