# Reflection Vector (Ray Tracing)

Tags: optics, measurements, geometric-optics, topology

Snell's law of refraction at the interface between 2 isotropic media is given by the equation:
\begin{align} \tag{1}
n_1 \,\text{sin} \,\theta_1 = n_2 \, \text{sin}\,\theta_2
\end{align}

$\qquad$ where $\theta_1$ is the angle of incidence and $\theta_2$  the angle of refraction. $n_1$ is  the refractive index of the optical medium in front of the interface and $n_2$ is the refractive index of the optical medium behind the interface.

Eq.(1) can be expressed in vector form as
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
n_1(\textbf{i} \times \textbf{n}) = n_2 (\textbf{t} \times \textbf{n}) 
\end{equation}
$\qquad$ where $\textbf{i}$ and  $\textbf{t}$  are  the unit *directional* vector of the incident and transmitted ray respectively.   $\textbf{n}$ is the unit *normal* vector  to the interface  between the two media pointing from medium 1 with refractive index $n_1$ into medium 2 with refractive index $n_2$.  Similarly $\textbf{r}$ is the reflected ray vector.

How can the equation
\begin{align}\tag{3}
\textbf{t} = \mu \textbf{i} + n\sqrt{1- \mu^2[1-(\textbf{ni})^2]} - \mu \textbf{n}(\textbf{ni}) 
\end{align}
be used to derive the equation
\begin{equation}\tag{4}
\textbf{n} = \dfrac{\textbf{i}-\textbf{r}}{\sqrt{2[1-(\textbf{i}\textbf{r})]}}?
\end{equation}

$\qquad$Here $\mu = \dfrac{n_1}{n_2}$ and $\textbf{n}\textbf{i}= n_{\text{x}} i_{\text{x}} + n_{\text{y}}i_{\text{y}}  + n_{\text{z}} i_{\text{z}}$ denotes the dot (scalar) product of vectors $\textbf{n}$ and $\textbf{i}$.

In Ref.[1] it says that from Eq.(3) follows
\begin{align}\tag{5}
\textbf{r} = \textbf{i} - 2\textbf{n}(\textbf{n}\textbf{i})
\end{align}
By simple modification
\begin{align}\tag{6}
\textbf{n} = \dfrac{\textbf{i}-\textbf{r}}{2(\textbf{n}\textbf{i})}
\end{align}
It says that "...by calculating the dot products of vector $\textbf{n}$ with both sides of Eq.(6), one can express the dot product $(\textbf{n}\textbf{i})$ in the form as shown in Eq.(4)" which I can't follow )=

Could someone explain how equation (4) is derived?

References:

1. Antonín Mikš and Pavel Novák, Determination of unit normal vectors of aspherical surfaces given unit directional vectors of incoming and outgoing rays: comment, 2012 Optical Society of America, page 1356

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I wonder why all this Physics stuff (refraction, reflection, Snell's Law etc) in order to ask a pure simple mathematical question in Vector Calculus : that of the normalization of a vector.

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{n}\boldsymbol{=}\dfrac{\mathbf{i}\boldsymbol{\!-\!}\mathbf{r}}{\Vert\mathbf{i}\boldsymbol{\!-\!}\mathbf{r}\Vert}
\tag{01}\label{01}    
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\Vert\mathbf{i}\boldsymbol{\!-\!}\mathbf{r}\Vert^{\bf 2}\boldsymbol{=}\Vert\mathbf{i}\Vert^{\bf 2}\boldsymbol{+}\Vert\mathbf{r}\Vert^{\bf 2}\boldsymbol{-}2(\mathbf{i}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{r})=1\boldsymbol{+}1\boldsymbol{-}2(\mathbf{i}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{r})\boldsymbol{=}2\left[1\boldsymbol{-}(\mathbf{i}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{r})\right]
\tag{02}\label{02}    
\end{equation} 
that is
\begin{equation}
\Vert\mathbf{i}\boldsymbol{\!-\!}\mathbf{r}\Vert\boldsymbol{=}\sqrt{2\left[1\boldsymbol{-}(\mathbf{i}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{r})\right]\vphantom{\frac12}}
\tag{03}\label{03}    
\end{equation} 
so
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{n}\boldsymbol{=}\dfrac{\mathbf{i}\boldsymbol{\!-\!}\mathbf{r}}{\sqrt{2\left[1\boldsymbol{-}(\mathbf{i}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{r})\right]\vphantom{\frac12}}}
\tag{04}\label{04}    
\end{equation}

$=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=$

**EDIT**

\begin{equation}
\left.
\begin{cases}
\mathbf{n}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{i}\boldsymbol{=}\cos\theta\\
\:\mathbf{i}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{r}\boldsymbol{=}\cos(\pi\!\boldsymbol{-}\!2\theta)\!\boldsymbol{=}\!\boldsymbol{-}\!\cos2\theta  
\end{cases}\!\!
\right\} 
\stackrel{\cos2\theta\boldsymbol{=}2\cos^{2}\theta\boldsymbol{-}1}{\boldsymbol{=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!\Longrightarrow}}\boldsymbol{-}(\mathbf{i}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{r})\boldsymbol{=}2(\mathbf{n}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{i})^{2}\!\boldsymbol{-}\!1
\tag{05}\label{05}    
\end{equation}
that's why your equation (6)
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{n}\boldsymbol{=}\dfrac{\mathbf{i}\!\boldsymbol{-}\!\mathbf{r}}{2(\mathbf{n}\!\boldsymbol{\cdot}\!\mathbf{i})}
\tag{06}\label{06}    
\end{equation}

$=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=$

Related : [Snell's law in vector form](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/435512/snells-law-in-vector-form/436252#436252)