# What is the equation for the refracted vector when using Snell's Law with 3D vectors?

Tags: optics, vectors

[image]

As the title says, how would I obtain the vector $\mathbf t$ if the vector $\mathbf i$ and the refractive indices are known? I've tried for hours but I keep getting stuck. Is there an equation readily available?

Thank you.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/435512/snells-law-in-vector-form

Comment: In what system do you know the vector i? do you täte the normal ant tangential component as given?

Comment: @trula The point of vector equations is that they don’t require a particular coordinate system.