# Resource suggestion for optics based on vectors

Tags: optics, resource-recommendations, geometric-optics

I'm looking for a book which develops concepts similar to the one discussed [in this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/435512/).

Comment: What other concepts are you interested in expressing as vectors?

Comment: @boyfarrell reflection formula, to be honest, I'm looking for a general reference which also discusses the vector method of dealing with optics.

Comment: Vector optics derivations here for ray tracing https://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs148-10-summer/docs/2006--degreve--reflection_refraction.pdf

Comment: Thank you , that was of much help @boyfarrell