# How can we express Snell's law as $\mu_1\sin i = \mu_2\sin r = constant$ and also as $\mu_1(\hat{IR}\times\hat{N}) = \mu_2(\hat{RR}\times\hat{N} )$

Tags: optics, refraction, geometric-optics

$\hat{IR}$ refers to the unit vector denoting the incident ray unit vector
$\hat{RR}$ refers to the unit vector denoting the refracted ray unit vector
$\hat{N}$ refers to the unit vector denoting the normal unit vector

Things that I know about cross product: $\overrightarrow{A} \times \overrightarrow{B} = AB\sin\theta$.

[Snell's law in vector form](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/435512/snells-law-in-vector-form) 
I referred to this link but I can't understand any of the explanations about how we can arrive to the cross product form of Snell's Law

Comment: This is exactly (a subset of) the question you link to. If you don't say _what_ you don't understand about the answers there, its not going to be possible to give you an answer.

Comment: Regarding the first part of the title question: I am confused what there is to know, Snell's law _is_ the statement that $\mu_1 \sin i = \mu_2 \sin r$.

Comment: I found the explanations too difficult to understand, so i was hoping that if someone could simplify it for me...

Comment: Welcome to PSE. Note that the cross product of two vectors is a vector too, not a scalar as it  seems that you wrongly know. More precisely : $\mathbf a \boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf b \boldsymbol{=} \left(|\mathbf a ||\mathbf b|\sin\theta\right)\mathbf n$  where $\mathbf n$ the unit vector normal to the plane of $\mathbf a ,\mathbf b$ obeying the right hand rule.

Comment: Related :[Why one should follow Snell's law for shortest time?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/257140/why-one-should-follow-snells-law-for-shortest-time/257331#257331).

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Notation in Figure-01 :
\begin{align}
   n_1,n_2 & \boldsymbol{=} \texttt{indices of refraction}
   \nonumber\\
   \theta_1,\theta_2 & \boldsymbol{=} \texttt{angles of incidence and transmission}
   \nonumber\\
   \mathbf i & \boldsymbol{=} \texttt{unit vector on incident ray}
   \nonumber\\
   \mathbf t & \boldsymbol{=} \texttt{unit vector on transmitted ray}
   \nonumber\\
   \mathbf n & \boldsymbol{=} \texttt{unit vector normal to the interface of the two media} 
   \nonumber\\
   \mathbf k & \boldsymbol{=} \texttt{unit vector normal to the plane of }\mathbf i,\mathbf t,\mathbf n
   \nonumber 
\end{align}

Snell's law is expressed as
\begin{equation}
   n_1\sin\theta_1\boldsymbol{=}n_2\sin\theta_2
   \tag{01}\label{01}
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
   \sin\theta_2\boldsymbol{=}\mu\sin\theta_1\,,\qquad \mu\boldsymbol{=}\dfrac{n_1}{n_2}
   \tag{02}\label{02}
\end{equation}
so
\begin{equation}
   \underbrace{\left(\sin\theta_2\right)\mathbf k}_{\left(\mathbf n\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf t\right)}\boldsymbol{=}\mu\underbrace{\left[\left(\sin\theta_1\right)\mathbf k\right]}_{\left(\mathbf n\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf i\right)}
   \tag{03}\label{03}
\end{equation}
that is Snell's law in vector form
\begin{equation}
\left(\mathbf n\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf t\right)\boldsymbol{=}\mu\left(\mathbf n\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf i\right)
  \tag{04}\label{04}
\end{equation}

Comment: Very nice your answers.

Comment: @Sebastiano : Welcome, my friend.